# How can I print this sequence of numbers using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to try this sequence in PHP: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. The condition is I can use only one loop.

I tried this code and I know it will infinite after it prints 0. But I do not find any way to fix it.

```
<?php
for($i = 10; $i >= 0; $i--){
echo $i;
if($i == 0){
    echo $i++;
}

}
```

Comment: Hint: `range()`, `array_merge()`, and `array_reverse()`

Comment: Another hint: keyword `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can't test it but I think it works:

```
<?php
$x = 10;
$cond = "DESC";
for($i = 20; $i >= 0; $i--){
echo $x; 
If ( $x == 1 )  $cond = "ASC";
$cond == "DESC" ? $x-- : $x++;
}
?>
```

If you want to have a more simple solution you can use array:

```
<?php
$arr = Array (10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

foreach ($arr as $int){
echo $int; 
}
?>
```

Comment: You can always [test online](https://3v4l.org/bN6lP). You overshot it a bit.

Comment: It works. But is there any simpler solution?

Comment: See in the answer another simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a one-liner, if you're looking for "simple":

```php
foreach (array_merge(range(10, 1, 1), range(3, 10, 1)) as $i) {
    echo "$i ";
}
```

Result:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

This makes the two arrays, `[ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]` and `[ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]`, concatenates them, and then runs through the resultant array.